# Horizontal List View add Footer View

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm using this Horizontal Listview [here](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)  and i need to add a  layout at the end of the list ... it does not support     `addFooter()` so I'm stuck

I want to add a "load more" button at the end

Answer (score 0):

you must use Custom Horizantal Listview.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative and a bit dirty solution is to add a dummy item with a specific flag to your backing list of the adapter. In `getView` check for this dummy item with the help of the flag and inflate the footer view.

**Be cautious when updating the list.** You should remove the last dummy item and add the additional list and then add the dummy item if required

Lets say this is your list item.

```
class Item {
    String title;
    String imageUrl;
    boolean flagFooter;//this is the flag which will be set when the view is a dummy view
}
```

The getView method can look something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Item i = getItem(position);
    //check whether a view needs to be inflated or not
    if (convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        //check whether the view is the footer view or not
        if(i.flagFooter){
            holder.flagFooter = true;
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);
        }else{
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
        }
        //assign holder views all findViewById goes here

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        //check whether the view is the footer view or not
        if(i.flagFooter){
            holder.flagFooter = true;
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer, null);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            //check if the view which is being reused is a footer view 
            //if it is footer view a list row view should be used.
            if(holder.flagFooter){
                holder.flagFooter = false;
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
        }
    }

    //update view here
    return convertView;

}
```

The view holder

```
class ViewHolder{
    TextView title;
    ImageView img;
    boolean footer;
}
```

As I have mentioned before this is a dirty way of doing the job but works just fine, have used this kind of approach in the past.